# React Navigation: Passing down screenProps to custom navigator

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-navigation

My code is based off this example on https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/blob/master/examples/NavigationPlayground/js/CustomTabs.js

I would like to pass down props from Redux to the screens in the custom tab router, but I am not sure how. I had used the connect function to connect mapStateToProps and actions to my parent component, OwnListingScreen. I have 3 screens in the custom tab router.

```
const CustomTabRouter = TabRouter(
  {
    Details: {
      screen: DetailsScreen,
      path: '',
    },
    Media: {
      screen: MediaScreen,
      path: 'media',
    },
    Reviews: {
      screen: CreateReviewFlow,
      path: 'reviews',
    },
  },
  {
    // Change this to start on a different tab
    initialRouteName: 'Details',
  }
);
```

Doing this doesn't work, I get "node has not been attached to a view" error

```
<CustomTabs screenProps = {this.props.listingAttributes} />
```

Comment: u found any solution to this? 
Can please show some light on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45912318/redux-for-maintaing-data-with-react-stack-navigation-stackwise?noredirect=1#comment78783610_45912318 then

Comment: yo @subhajit in the end i used redux to pull the data manually at each screen individually using mapStateToProps