# Redux for maintaing data with React Stack Navigation stackwise

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, react-navigation

I have a screen A , which contains navigable components. One of these components navigates to screen A itself but with different data passed from the triggered component.

I am using Redux , and React-navigation.

Please help me to know how can I store data of screen according to React Stack Navigation Stage.

- Stack 4 --> Product Screen[id=103]
- Stack 3 --> Product Screen[id=102]
- Stack 2 --> Product Screen[id=101](suppose it contains related
  products which navigates to Product Screen itself with different
  params via this.props.navigation state params)
- Stack 1 --> Home

Now currently my screen shows data like this from the store:

```
class ProductDetail extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
        debugger;
        this.props.getProduct(this.props.navigation.state.params.productId);
    }

render() {
        const { goBack } = this.props.navigation;
        const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
  return (
    <View>
     {
        this.props.product.isProductLoadingCompleted && (
          <Text>{productDetail.name}</Text>
          <View>
            //displaying all related products [onPress of this component ProductDetail Component opens with different id]
          </View>
     }    
    </View>
  }
}
```

Now suppose I am calling

```
this.props.navigation.goBack();
```

from Stack 4 , then it will show data of product id = 103 instead of product id = 102. To solve this this, either I have to put condition to fetch data again with the current screen product id which I do not think is a good application.

So how can I store the data so that product id 103 sticks to Screen at Stack 4 and product id 102 at stack 3 and so on ?

Comment: You can store the state for each component on the component. Not all state must be stored in redux. I only store states in redux if the data must be shared among more than 1 screen.

Comment: No data is not being shared among other screens. for product id 102 and 103 data are different. I need to show the pre-fetched data in the stacked screens.